# Execute SU command

Tags: android, shell, superuser

I'm developping an app that could set Immersive mode on Rooted devices , but i can't execute the command , On the main activity i check if the device is rooted, if it is , i start an intent to open the second activity where i have the button that needs to execute the command :

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 import eu.chainfire.libsuperuser.Shell;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     Button btnSU;


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         btnSU = findViewById(R.id.bv_checkSu);

         btnSU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  checkSU();
             }
         });




     }

     private void checkSU(){

           try {

                 if (Shell.SU.available()) {


                Toast.makeText(this, "Congratulation you're SU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, setScreenActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();


            }else{

                Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry No SU shell Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sorry an Error has Occured",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


}
```

The setScreenActivity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class setScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnFull;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    btnFull = findViewById(R.id.bv_Full);

    btnFull.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Immersive im = new Immersive();
                im.setImmersiveFull();

            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });





}
}
```

On the setScreenActivity i set a listener on the Button and then it Intanciate an "Immersive class object where i apply the "setImmersiveFull() Method "

When I run the app on my real phone ,everythings goes really well even when i click on the button full , the toast appears but the screen don't change at all , that's pretty curious because when i run the command on the Terminal emulator application , the screen change to immersive mode .

Here's the Immersive Class :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Immersive {

public Context ctx;

public void setImmersiveFull() throws IOException {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(String[] {"settings put global policy_control immersive.full=apps,-com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"});

    Toast.makeText(ctx,"Full Immersive Mode Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

public void setImmersiveNoNavBar() throws IOException{

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(String[] {"settings put global policy_control immersive.navigation=apps,-com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"});

    Toast.makeText(ctx,"No Navigation Bar Immersive Mode Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void setImmersiveNoStatusBar() throws IOException{


    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(String[] {"settings put global policy_control immersive.status=apps,-com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox"});

    Toast.makeText(ctx,"No Status Bar Immersive Mode Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

public void setStockMode() throws IOException{


    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rt.exec(String[] {"settings put global policy_control immersive="});

    Toast.makeText(ctx,"Stock Mode Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}




}
```

My Devices is rooted and it runs Android Oreo 8.0.0
Any idea On i should do to run this command as SU programatically ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `Shell.SU.run("command")` insteadof creating a process using `Runtime`